# Oracle Rules - Imported Java Fact causes UndefinedException when deployed

Tags: java, jdeveloper, oracle-rules

In JDeveloper 12c, I have created a BPM application/project. Project SOA Settings are `Composite With Business Rule`.

The project has a Mediator and is exposed as a REST service. I am deploying using the `IntegratedWebLogicServer`

The XML Facts are rather generic including lists of fields, sub-lists, and sub-sub-lists, etc. This makes navigating the inputs more challenging.

I created a Java class with some static methods that more easily retrieve the data based on an expression. I created a jar with that class and then imported the class into the Java Facts. I then created rules that call the static methods on that Java Fact.

The rules validate just fine and I can now successfully run the rules from the "Test" tab of the rules. I get expected results. However, when I deploy the project it seems like the imported jar is not deployed along with it since I get the following exception:

```
oracle.rules.rl.exceptions.UndefinedException: The symbol "mypackage.MyUtil" is undefined.
at line 22 column 14 in /Ruleset(main)
```

I thought that importing the class in the Java Facts would cause my custom jar or at least the class that I imported to be deployed. But it seems that this may not be the case. Am I missing something? Is there somewhere in my project that I can place the jar to cause it to be deployed?

I tried adding the jar to the Libraries and Classpath entries of the project. I also tried adding it to a user library located in the project and adding that to the Libraries and Classpath list. But both had no effect.

I am new to JDeveloper and Oracle BPM, so I'm hoping there's something simple I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the jar to this directory:

`MyBpmApplication\MyBpmProject\SOA\SCA-INF\lib`